# VB.net WebBrowser1 getting value from javascript on call

Tags: javascript, dom, browser, webbrowser-control, domdocument

Hey all i have this javascript within my VB code that checks for if a player is paused or running:

```
Dim isPlaying As String = WebBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript("player.states.isPlaying", "JavaScript")
```

It executes without any errors but the value for **usPlaying** is **Nothing**.

If i do this:

```
Dim isPlaying As String = WebBrowser1.Document.Window.DomWindow.execscript("alert(player.states.isPlaying)", "JavaScript")
```

I get a pop up saying either **false** or **true** so from that i know its actually calling the javascript and returning the correct value.

My problem is that i need to be able to save that returned value to my **isPlaying** variable in order to check things within my VB program.

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wahoo! I got it :)

```
Dim isPlaying As Boolean = WebBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("eval", {"player.states.isPlaying;"})
```